# How would a group of extra-terrestrial infiltrators go about destroying a free market economy

Tags: humans, aliens, economy, earth, finances

Let's say that a small group (around 20 or so) of well-equipped, highly intelligent ETs have secretly made their way on to Earth. They have all the knowledge they need of our various languages and cultures to fit in, along with disguise technology so they can assume the identity of anyone.

Now let's add that they are also superhumanly skilled at trading and market manipulation, and have made it their goal to cause as much turmoil in as many economies as possible without getting their hands dirty (directly anyway).

Assuming a generous starting capital from having assimilated the identities of various wealthy private entities, how much can they influence the markets? Can they actually irreversably damage the global economy?

Answer (score 1):

- Replace various wealthy decisionmakers, and then start a coordinated trading scheme which destroys wealth, and lures others along.
  *If* X *is selling* Y, *he probably has a good reason. Let's do it, too.*
- Buy a few companies with a critical niche in the global supply chain, and then create artificial shortages.
- Introduce selected bits of alien technology to the markets when they are most disruptive.
- Find a few overextended banks, buy up loans to them through strawmen, and then call the debt.

Comment: Producing massive amounts of counterfeit currency would also have a significant impact on a capitalist economy.